# Determine the solution of this PDE using the characteristic method (parametric form).

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Determine the solution of this EDP using the characteristic method (parametric form).

$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial{w}}{\partial x}=0 \\
w(x,0)=e^{2x} \,\,\,\, \text{for $(x,0)$ in $\gamma$ }
\end{equation}$

> I don't understand much of this method... I'm stuck in some parts, i hope you can help me to understand this (:

**My attempt**

Note $\gamma$ is a function such that his point are of the form $(e^{2x},0)$.

We need find a parametric solution for the superfice $S$ defined by the graph of $z=w(x,0)$.

Then

$(x(r,s),t(r,s),w(x(r,s),t(r,s))$ where $w(x(r,s),t(r,s))=w(r,s).$

If $s=0$ we have the parametrization of the condition $w(x,0)=e^{2x}$.

Then

$(x(r,0),t(r,0),w(x,0))=(e^{2x},0,e^{2x})$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me? I don't understand very well this.

Comment: i think i solved it

Comment: one moment the lost moment needs work

Comment: Yes!! Thanks for all @RyanHowe and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = 0 \\ w(x,0) = e^{2x}    \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{1}$$

We parameterize the curve by $r$ such that $\gamma = \{ (r,0)\}$ the characteristics are given by

$$ \frac{dt}{ds}(r,s) = 1 \\ \frac{dx}{ds}(r,s)  = -1 \\ \frac{dz}{ds}(r,s) = 0  \tag{2}$$

with the initial condition given as

$$ t(r,0) = 0 \\ x(r,0)  = 0 \\ z(r,0) = e^{2r}  \tag{3}$$

when we solve the system

$$ t(r,s) = s+c_{1}(r) \\ x(r,s)  = c_{2}(r)-s \\ z(r,s) = c_{3}(r) \tag{4}$$
imposing the initial condition
$$ t(r,s) = s \\ x(r,s)  = -s\\ z(r,s) = e^{2r} \tag{5}$$

now

$$ r(x,t) =x  \\  s(x,t) =  t \tag{6} $$

$$  z(r(x,t),s(x,t)) = \phi(x) = e^{2x}  \tag{7}  $$

note that the solution for the characteristic is given by

$$ w(x,t) = e^{2(x-t)} \tag{8} $$

Comment: I need a  a solution using the parametric form of this method! Thanks for you take the time in answer.

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf is it like $\Gamma$ on page 9